# Bar color according to height in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

How can I change the color of bars in a bar-chart to be in a scale according to its height? Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
year = c(2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2002,2003,2003,2004,2004,2004,2004,2005)
df = data.frame(year)

ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(year,fill=year))
```

I need the colors to be in a scale according to the count of each year (light blue for years with a low counts and dark blue for higher counts, for example).

I could do it by using the counts as the data frame (2000;2, 2001;3, etc.), but that would require a lot of work in other parts of my code, so I'd rather keep the data in this format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `..count..` computed by `ggplot()` function as your fill variable.

```
ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(year,fill=..count..))
```